# How to have path displayed in list when searching in finder?

Tags: finder, search

So I am looking for util.js, and finder found many, but the path is not an option for display in the table. Is there a way to get the full path in the table as well? Otherwise I have to down-arrow through the list for each one and look at the bar at the bottom. And there are so many!  I would like to use the empty area on the right for the path.

[image: My Finder Search Experience]

Answer (score 1):

You can try with [EasyFind](https://www.devontechnologies.com/apps/freeware). It's a really good application for search files.

Comment: Yup. On my 'indispensable utility' list.

Answer (score 0):

As well a great front end for Spotlight, [HoudahSpot](https://www.houdah.com/houdahSpot/) is able to display more columns - including Path.

[image]

It is not cheap, but well worth it if you are a serious user of Spotlight.